# Copy text only contained within quotes "" from a file

Tags: text-processing

`/etc/opendkim/keys/"$(hostname)"/default.txt` contains the following

```
default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; r=postmaster; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZYVW/965FePDPfxTIUT5ScJ3mZZZZZZZZ8BWNgLFS6JtZZZZZZZZZZZZZZk7Sc+eQwY6tHAQvHczJTTkICB4WW9mtc5PlFAZNuC9X3oYTeIp8cpScBmaIaP+t35fwh+PL7ZZZZZZZZZZ3ZxoFsJD6pvCqx+TCbZZZZZZZZ5JQIDAQAB" ; ----- DKIM default for mydomain.com
```

I want to copy only the stuff inside of the quotes (not including them) `v=DKIM1; r=postmaster; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZYVW/965FePDPfxTIUT5ScJ3mZZZZZZZZ8BWNgLFS6JtZZZZZZZZZZZZZZk7Sc+eQwY6tHAQvHczJTTkICB4WW9mtc5PlFAZNuC9X3oYTeIp8cpScBmaIaP+t35fwh+PL7ZZZZZZZZZZ3ZxoFsJD6pvCqx+TCbZZZZZZZZ5JQIDAQAB` into another file.

How can I do this?

Comment: `awk -F\" '{print $2}' file > new file`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/' filename
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there is more than one quoted string per line.

Answer (score 2):

If there is definitely only one quoted string per line, then your most performant possible solution will involve `cut`:

```
cut -d\" -f2 <in >out
```

If there can be more than one quoted string per line, then you could do:

```
sed 's/[^"]*\("[^"]*"\)[^"]*/ \1 /g' <in >out
```

...which will print only all double-quoted strings per line, each separated w/ a leading and trailing space.

Neither of the above solutions is *other-quote* aware, though. Neither one will ignore backslash escaped quotes, or double-quoted strings contained within hard-quotes, for example.